# Is there any way to get the screenshot of Flare3D?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flare, flare3d

I want to save Flare3d scene as a png file using actionscript

this what I have tried , i am able to save file but image is not transparent(it is showing black background) which i want to remove

```
var bmpd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(scene.viewPort.width, scene.viewPort.height,true,0x00000000 );
scene.context.clear();
scene.render();

scene.context.drawToBitmapData( bmpd );

var ba:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bmpd);

var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, saveSuccessful1);

file.save(ba, "image3d.png");
```

[image: Saved image using this code]

is there any better way to this to get transparent image

thanks

Comment: it actually nothing to do with flare3d, its pure as3.

Answer (score 0):

It actually created transparent image

The last property of BitmapData is fill color, which will fill with what ever you said

```
var bmpd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(scene.viewPort.width, scene.viewPort.height,true,0xFFFFFF );
```

It will fill with white background now

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy, just set zero alpha in **scene.context.clear(0,0,0,0);**

Of course, you already correctly set BitmapData to transparent and 0 fill color.